# How implement dynamic testimonials and carousel in django python

Tags: python, django

Im facing implementing the dynamic testimonials and carousel in django python, means i need to content in models that so present in front below i mention my code of implemetions

`template.html`

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for p in tests %}
          {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
            <div class="item active">
          {% else %}
              <div class="item">
          {% endif %}
                <h3>{{ p.title }}</h3>
              </div>`enter code here`
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
</div>
```

`view.py`

```
def home(request):
    test=Testimonials.objects.all().order_by('id')[:13]
    template = loader.get_template('hme/home.html')
    context = {
        'tests':test,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really want to do, but your *views.py* can be rewrite as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
    tests = Testimonials.objects.order_by('id')[:13]
    return render(request, 'hme/home.html', {'tests': tests})
```